# Adding columns from different tables in SQL Server within a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I am writing this stored procedure to get details from 4 differnt tables using join and simple logic, but while acculmulating it all in the end using UNION os not working as I am getting the error : expecting AS,ID or quoted_id, please suggest what am I doing wrong in this.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[cp_RejectionAnalysis] 
    (@RunDate DATE --'20150501')
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 

    --DECLARE @RunDate DATE = '20150401'
    DECLARE @StartDate DATE = DATEADD(DD, -30, @RunDate);

    DECLARE @GeRejectionDate AS TABLE (PayerName VARCHAR(120), 
                                       ClaimCount INT);

    WITH  rejections AS 
    (
        SELECT 
            i.Number,
            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN far.SubmissionDate < @RunDate THEN far.ClaimKey ELSE NULL END) AS TotalRejectsFirst30, 
            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN far.SubmissionDate = @RunDate THEN far.ClaimKey ELSE NULL END) AS TotalRejectsRunDate
        FROM 
            table1 far
        INNER JOIN 
            table2 i ON far.InsurerInfoKey = i.InsurerKey
        WHERE 
            far.isRejection = 1
            AND (far.MessageDate >= @StartDate AND far.MessageDate <= @RunDate)
        GROUP BY 
            i.Number), 
    totalclaims AS 
    (
        SELECT 
            i.Number,
            SUM(CASE WHEN ts.SubmissionDate < @RunDate THEN ts.TotalClaims ELSE 0 END) AS TotalClaimsFirst30, 
            SUM(CASE WHEN ts.SubmissionDate = @RunDate THEN ts.TotalClaims ELSE 0 END) AS TotalClaimsRunDate
        FROM 
            table3 ts
        INNER JOIN 
            table2 i ON ts.InsurerInfoKey = i.InsurerKey
        WHERE 
            ts.SubmissionDate >= @StartDate 
            AND ts.SubmissionDate <= @RunDate
        GROUP BY 
            i.Number
        --ORDER BY i.Number
        )
    /*, PaymentRejectionDetails AS (
        (SELECT DISTINCT ra.Message AS ErrorMessage, ra.ErrorListKey AS ErrorListKey
                        FROM dimErrorListRejectionAnalysis ra
                            INNER JOIN table1 far on ra.ErrorListKey= far.ErrorListKey
                        WHERE (far.MessageDate >= @StartDate AND far.MessageDate <= @RunDate))
                    UNION
                        (SELECT DISTINCT QcHistClaimId AS ClaimId FROM  table1 far
                        WHERE (far.MessageDate >= @StartDate AND far.MessageDate <= @RunDate))
                    UNION
                        (SELECT DISTINCT SITEID FROM table4 ds
                            INNER JOIN table1 far ON ds.sitekey=far.sitekey
                        WHERE (far.MessageDate >= @StartDate AND far.MessageDate <= @RunDate))  
                )*/
        , ClaimsID AS
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT ClaimId 
            FROM table1 far
            WHERE (far.MessageDate >= @StartDate AND far.MessageDate <= @RunDate))
        , SiteId AS
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT SITEID 
            FROM table4 ds
            INNER JOIN table1 far ON ds.sitekey = far.sitekey
            WHERE (far.MessageDate >= @StartDate AND far.MessageDate <= @RunDate))
    SELECT * 
    INTO D 
    FROM
        (SELECT ClaimId FROM ClaimsID 
         UNION 
         SELECT SITEID FROM SiteId
         UNION
         SELECT 
             r.PayerNumber, r.TotalRejectsFirst30, 
             r.TotalRejectsRunDate, 
             ISNULL(t.TotalClaimsFirst30, 0) AS ClaimsFirst30, 
             ISNULL(t.TotalClaimsRunDate, 0) AS ClaimsRunDate
         FROM 
             rejections r
         LEFT OUTER JOIN 
             totalclaims t ON t.PayerNumber = r.PayerNumber)
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invalid use of [`UNION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms180026.aspx) here

```
 SELECT ClaimId FROM ClaimsID 
 UNION 
 SELECT SITEID FROM SiteId
 UNION
 SELECT r.PayerNumber, r.TotalRejectsFirst30, r.TotalRejectsRunDate, ISNULL(t.TotalClaimsFirst30, 0) AS ClaimsFirst30, ISNULL(t.TotalClaimsRunDate, 0) AS ClaimsRunDate
 FROM rejections r
```

First you need to understand the scenario of `UNION`

> Combines the results of two or more queries into a single result set
>   that includes all the rows that belong to all queries in the union.
>   The UNION operation is different from using joins that combine columns
>   from two tables.

The following are basic rules for combining the result sets of two queries by using `UNION`:

1. The number and the order of the columns must be the same in all queries.
2. The data types must be compatible.

**EDIT 2:**

i'm not sure what you really want, and you didn't response to my comment.
but my guess you can try using `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT 
    r.PayerNumber,
    r.TotalRejectsFirst30,
    r.TotalRejectsRunDate,
    ISNULL(t.TotalClaimsFirst30, 0) AS ClaimsFirst30,
    ISNULL(t.TotalClaimsRunDate, 0) AS ClaimsRunDate,
    c.ClaimId as ClaimId
FROM rejections r LEFT JOIN ClaimsID c On r.ClaimId=c.ClaimId
```

Comment: So, how can i achieve the results in my SP, please suggest what can be used instead of UNION.

Comment: what are you expecting from this `UNION`?? @architsoni

Comment: I think i didn't apply the concept correctly here, what i wanted was to have the different columns from different tables using UNION (allegedly) in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the asterisks around the last block and add an alias for the sub query.

```
            *SELECT * INTO D FROM
            (
            SELECT ClaimId FROM ClaimsID UNION SELECT SITEID FROM SiteId
            UNION
            SELECT r.PayerNumber, r.TotalRejectsFirst30, r.TotalRejectsRunDate, ISNULL(t.TotalClaimsFirst30, 0) AS ClaimsFirst30, ISNULL(t.TotalClaimsRunDate, 0) AS ClaimsRunDate
            FROM rejections r
            LEFT OUTER JOIN totalclaims t ON t.PayerNumber = r.PayerNumber)*
```

You can't union rows with number/type of fields. What is the end result you expect from this whole procedure? By the way, posting the create scripts for the tables would help answer the question.

Comment: Yes @tubelius, my DB team suggested to use of joins instead of using UNION.. Thanks for your time and suggestions.